# MonthCalendar Control not "obeying"? (CalendarDimensions)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The MonthCalendar's CandendarDimnesions is set to 1,1. But when run in large resolutions the dimensions Y increases. Screenshots are attached for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

How do I make sure it won't grow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `Anchor` set to **Top, Bottom, Right**. If you don't want the Calendar size to change, don't anchor to **Top** *and* **Bottom** - only one or the other.